# Amazon MWS - Set Seller Memo (Notes) to the order from Order Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I am developing an application to get the orders from Amazon in **Asp.net** with **C#**. I am able to get the Amazon orders using "**ListOrders**" method of "**Orders**" API.

The **Amazon MWS Scratchpad** is available **[HERE](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html)**

I am trying to update the order information of Amazon. I want to update "Seller Memo" field of the order using any API method or XML request call. (Please see below Image)

[image: Order Screen Contain Seller Memo Field]

I have try the "SubmitFeed" method of "Feeds" API. But it not works.

Please, help me to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for it. I am posting the answer for reference of other person.

First Generate Inventory Document for: AmazonEnvelope
Please refer link: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2380272

Then InvokeFeed like below:

```
    public static void InvokeSubmitFeed(MarketplaceWebService.MarketplaceWebService service, SubmitFeedRequest request, List<string> OrderTrackingInfoIds)
    {
        try
        {

            SubmitFeedResponse response = service.SubmitFeed(request);

            Console.WriteLine("        SubmitFeedResponse");
            if (response.IsSetSubmitFeedResult())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("            SubmitFeedResult");
                Util.log("            SubmitFeedResult");
                SubmitFeedResult submitFeedResult = response.SubmitFeedResult;
                if (submitFeedResult.IsSetFeedSubmissionInfo())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("                FeedSubmissionInfo");
                    Util.log("            FeedSubmissionInfo");
                    FeedSubmissionInfo feedSubmissionInfo = submitFeedResult.FeedSubmissionInfo;
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetFeedSubmissionId())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    FeedSubmissionId");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.FeedSubmissionId);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Total Updates :" + result.ToString());
                        Util.log("Total Updates :" + result.ToString());
                        Util.log("                      FeedSubmissionId");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.FeedSubmissionId);
                    }
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetFeedType())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    FeedType");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.FeedType);

                        Util.log("                      FeedType");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.FeedType);
                    }
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetSubmittedDate())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    SubmittedDate");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.SubmittedDate);
                        Util.log("                      SubmittedDate");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.SubmittedDate);
                    }
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetFeedProcessingStatus())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    FeedProcessingStatus");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.FeedProcessingStatus);
                        Util.log("                      FeedProcessingStatus");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.FeedProcessingStatus);
                    }
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetStartedProcessingDate())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    StartedProcessingDate");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.StartedProcessingDate);
                        Util.log("                      StartedProcessingDate");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.StartedProcessingDate);
                    }
                    if (feedSubmissionInfo.IsSetCompletedProcessingDate())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("                    CompletedProcessingDate");
                        Console.WriteLine("                        {0}", feedSubmissionInfo.CompletedProcessingDate);
                        Util.log("                      CompletedProcessingDate");
                        Util.log("                        " + feedSubmissionInfo.CompletedProcessingDate);

                    }
                }
            }

            if (response.IsSetResponseMetadata())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("            ResponseMetadata");
                MarketplaceWebService.Model.ResponseMetadata responseMetadata = response.ResponseMetadata;
                if (responseMetadata.IsSetRequestId())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("                RequestId");
                    Console.WriteLine("                    {0}", responseMetadata.RequestId);
                    Util.log("                          RequestId");
                    Util.log("                        " + responseMetadata.RequestId);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("            ResponseHeaderMetadata");
            Console.WriteLine("                RequestId");
            Console.WriteLine("                    " + response.ResponseHeaderMetadata.RequestId);
            Console.WriteLine("                ResponseContext");
            Console.WriteLine("                    " + response.ResponseHeaderMetadata.ResponseContext);
            Console.WriteLine("                Timestamp");
            Console.WriteLine("                    " + response.ResponseHeaderMetadata.Timestamp);

        }
        catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + ex.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + ex.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Error Type: " + ex.ErrorType);
            Console.WriteLine("Request ID: " + ex.RequestId);
            Console.WriteLine("XML: " + ex.XML);
            Console.WriteLine("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " + ex.ResponseHeaderMetadata);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been requested as a feature, but it is not available yet as of the end of 2015.  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=248610